# web api 2 individual authentication default login method

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I have the default Register method in the Account controller functioning but I see that in Startup.Auth.cs file this following code:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

Do I have to create a Token method?  I'm a little lost on how to login for a user.

Comment: You have to create your own OAuth provider for telling your app how to process the login credentials. Within that you will be able to specify what claims you want the bearer token to contain, how to log an attempt, and how to behave when a failed login occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's doesn't seem to be clearly explained anywhere. I had found a great example http://johnatten.com/2014/09/21/asp-net-identity-2-0-introduction-to-working-with-identity-2-0-and-web-api-2-2/  which didn't have a login method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, to "login" you submit a Post to the /token endpoint.

Sunil Ravulapalli has this great video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk0PwKO4MP0 which describes the following info:

Request Header:
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Body:
username=tom&password=passw0rd1&grant_type=password